# Magnitude of complex numbers

Tags: java, complex-numbers, sqrt

I'm working on a project that deals with complex numbers, to explain more *(a + bi)* where "*a*" is the real part of the complex number and "*b*" is the imaginary part of it. (a and b are real numbers but "i" isn't)

I'm having a hard time with implementing a *magnitude* method, instead of getting back a real number as a *double* i get *infinity*.

This is what I'm trying to implement: | (a + bi) | = √(a^2 + b^2)

a snippet off my code

```
public double mag(){
    /**
     * Compute the magnitude of this complex number.
     * 
     */
    //final double re is the real part
    //final double I'm is the imaginary part 
    double mag = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.re, 2) + Math.pow(this.im, 2));

    return mag;
}
```

say, if both real and imaginary numbers were Double.MAX_VALUE. why would mag return *infinity* instead of 1.8961503816218352E154 ?

Comment: Infinity is actually the correct answer here, because `| x + xi |` is `√2 * |x|`, which will always be greater than `x`, and anything greater than `Double.MAX_VALUE` in floating point is infinity by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinity numbers are numbers larger than Double.MAX_VALUE or smaller than -Double.MAX_VALUE. 1.0/0.0 is infinite. So is 2*Double.MAX_VALUE.

`Math.pow(Double.MAX_VALUE,2)` is obviously larger than `Double.MAX_VALUE`. Squaring of a largest possible number will result into something that regular number system can't represent.

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.re, 2) + Math.pow(this.im, 2))
==> Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Double.MAX_VALUE, 2) + Math.pow(Double.MAX_VALUE, 2))
==> Math.sqrt(Infinity + Infinity)
==> Infinity
```

Before the sqrt can be calculated, the squaring of a double max value resulted into infinity. you can't find sqrt of an Infinity number, so what you got it perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks buddha, i don't know how the double range slipped off my mind. but your answer is definitely correct. However, i got around my JUnit tester by declaring mag as Math.hypot(this.re, this.im).

Answer (score 0):

for double values if the value exceeds `Double.Max_value` then it returns `infinity`. As the other answer has shown so in your case it will return `infinity`. So for very big numbers you cannot do simple math operations. You better use `BigDecimal` for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return  1.8961503816218352E154
do this

```
    public double mag() {

     double x = this.re;
     double y = this.im;
     return Math.hypot(x, y);

}
```